# Converting constructor from 0.4.25 to latest version

Tags: solidity, constructor

The syntax of constructor in version 0.4.25 was

```
contract A {
   address newContract;
   function createContract(uint a, string memory b, address c) public {
       newContract = new B(a, b, c);
   }
}
contract B {
   uint aa;
   string bb;
   address cc;
   constructor(uint a, string memory b, address c) public {
      aa=a;
      bb=b;
      cc=c;
   }
 }
```

The syntax of constructor was changed from version 0.5
As of now the syntax of the constructor of version 0.8.5 is explained in their [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html?highlight=constructor#constructors)
but I'm not able to understand how to convert the above code to the latest solidity version.
Can someone help to convert the above code to version 0.8.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are just one change required, and one optional:

- [Required] Cast `new B` to an address. It is required since solc v0.5.0

```
newContract = address(new B(a, b, c));
```

- [Optional] Remove `public` from constructor. It is just a warning since solc v0.7.0.

```
constructor(uint a, string memory b, address c) {
```